# Looping Through UITableView with custom UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm making an app with a settings page that is set up as a UITableView with custom cells. These cells are set up like this:

[image]

I need to loop through a table of these cells each time one of the switches is changed. I need to check which switches are on to make an array of the user's preferred settings (in this case the cells that are on have their labels added to an array). Here is the code I was trying to use to do this:

```
for var x = 0; x < preferredDistances.count; x++ {

            var indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: x, inSection: 0)

            let cell : SettingsCell = settingsTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! SettingsCell

            if cell.settingsCellSwitch.on {
                preferredDistances.append(cell.settingsCellLabel.text!)
            }

        }
```

When trying to loop through the UITableView with this code, my cell return nil. What am I doing wrong in this block of code and how can I fix it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Would it be possible without looping through the cell. May be by reloading data or something ?

Comment: @GeneratorOfOne I need to loop through all the cells to check the values of the switches. If the switch is on, the label will be added to an array.

Comment: Are some of the rows scrolled off screen?  The cell for those rows will be nil.

Comment: @pbasdf No, its about 8 cells all on screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is fundamentally flawed. You are responsible for knowing which switches are enabled. Because table cells are reused, you can't reliably ask them what the switch is set to.

Here's another possible approach:

- When your view is initialized (for example, in `viewDidLoad()`), create an array with the default settings:

  ```
  var settings = [true, false, false, false, true, false]
  ```

  This array should be the same length as the array that you reference in `numberOfRowsInSection`.
- When a slider is updated (changed by the user), update the appropriate item in the array
- In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, use the relevant setting in the array to set the slider's value.

Comment: I was thinking about using this approach, how do I detect a switch being changed and get the index of the cell that was modified?

Comment: The switch can tell your cell, then the cell can tell your view controller… (using the delegation pattern)

Comment: Or you can use the hacky `viewWithTag(:_)` method, but I don't recommend that.

Comment: Can you link me to an example of the delegation pattern in use?

Comment: @ACR There are lots of examples online from many years of UITableView questions :) [Here's one example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25666440/1445366), but I'm sure you can find more.

Comment: @AaronBrager I've tried your answer and can't find a solution to one issue. When the user interacts with the switch, I don't know how to get the indexPath of the cell, so I can't modify my array. How would I get the indexPath for the cell in which the switch is located?

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is don't loop through cells to determine the state of their switches. You should have a model (could be as simple as an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`) backing your `UITableView` that stores the state of the switches (and that model gets updated whenever you update a switch).

That way, when it comes time to get the state of all the switches, you ask your model, instead of asking the view.

As one of the commentors pointed out, on iOS, `UITableViewCell`s are reused (if architected properly) which makes your current approach very un-scalable, as well.

Comment: Can I see an example of how to make a model?